# Datanucleus JDO setting fields to null

Tags: mysql, jdo, datanucleus

In an attempt to find another issue, my tests came up with the following bit of code.

```
public class TestPersistance {
 private static final PersistenceManagerFactory PMF = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("datanucleus.properties");
 public static final PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();
 static final TestUserDataDB ud = new TestUserDataDB();

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  TestPersistance tp = new TestPersistance();
  tp.createData();
 }

  @Test  public void createData()
 {
  assertTrue("Null machined id at start", ud.machineId != null);
  pm.currentTransaction().begin();
   try
   {
  pm.makePersistent(ud);
   }
   finally
   {
  pm.currentTransaction().commit();
   }
   assertTrue("Null machined id at end", ud.machineId != null);
 }
}
```

where the second assert fails.  ie. my object that I am asking to be persisted is being changed by the makePersistent call. The data is being stored in the database.
Any ideas?  Can any one confirm this.
using 
jdo-api-3.0.jar
datanucleus-core-2.2.0-release.jar
datanucleus-enhancer-2.1.3.jar
datanucleus-rdbms-2.2.0-release.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar

in eclipse with MySql database.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class TestUserDataDB {

 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 public Long id;

 @Persistent
 public String userid = "test1";
 @Persistent
 public String machineId = "test2";

 // local userid
 @Persistent
 public long uid = 1L;

 @Persistent
 public long systemTime = 123L;
 public long chk = 1234L;
 public long createTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

 public TestUserDataDB()
 {
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "TestUserDataDB [chk=" + chk + ", createTime=" + createTime
    + ", id=" + id + ", machineId=" + machineId + ", systemTime="
    + systemTime + ", uid=" + uid + ", userid=" + userid + "]";
 }



}
```

Properties file is

```
javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass=org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
datanucleus.metadata.validate=false

javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=root
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=yeahRight
datanucleus.autoCreateSchema=true
datanucleus.validateTables=false
datanucleus.validateConstraints=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you accessing fields directly ? Is the accessing class declared as PersistenceAware ? Well it isn't so you can't do that - use the getters.
What is "ud" object state before persist ? (transient?) what is it after persist ? (hollow?) What does the log say ? Chances are that it is in hollow state and then you access a field directly and it has no value (by definition, as per the spec) ... but since you didn't bother calling the getter it hasn't a chance to retrieve the value. And you likely also don't have "RetainValues" persistent property set

Suggest you familiarise yourself with the JDO spec and object lifecycle states

Comment: Sounds like I've got some reading to do.  Thought I could just save classes to the database and that was the end of it, obviously not.

Comment: ps.  Thanks, saved a lot of heartache.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it is necessary to access deserialized objects' attributes directly (i.e. if using GSON library for JSON serialization). In that case you can use:

```
MyClass copy = myPersistencyManager.detachCopy(myRetrievedInstance);
```